# Parallax image does not work on ion-slider for ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, slider, ionic4

I'm not able to get parallax effect to work with ionic4 ion-slider. I've tried examples from the original source code of idangero but none seem to work.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'slides-example',
  template: `
    <ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
      <ion-slide>
                <ion-img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/956981/milky-way-starry-sky-night-sky-star-956981.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"></ion-img>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  `
})
export class SlideExample {
  slideOpts = {
    effect: 'flip', // <-- this does not work either 
    parallax: true
  };
  constructor() {}
}
```